# How to append a div with also the script appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So I have a piece of code that appends some things to a webpage, those elements are called from a `JSON` file (`JSONP`).
This is the code that calls the `JSON` file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
(function($) {
var key= "12345";
var url = 'http://www.example.com/json.php?callback=?&auth=' + key + '';
var that = $(this);
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        $( "head" ).append(json.csBlock[0].pre);    
        $( "head" ).append(json.csBlock[0].markup); 
        $( "body" ).append(json.csBlock[0].div);
        $( "body" ).append(json.csBlock[0].script);
        $( "body" ).append(json.csBlock[0].frame);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
});
</script>
```

The thing is.. When I use this it will say:
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null`
This is because I call `$( "body" ).append(json.csBlock[0].script);`. Which contains the following code in the `JSON` file:

```
"script": "<script>$('.wblongbar').click(function(e) {  if($('.wbiFrame').hasClass('slide-up')) {$('.wbiFrame').addClass('slide-down', 200); $('.wblongbar').addClass('slide-downlongbar', 200); $('.wbiFrame').removeClass('slide-up'); $('.wblongbar').removeClass('slide-uplongbar'); } else {$('.wbiFrame').removeClass('slide-down'); $('.wblongbar').removeClass('slide-downlongbar'); $('.wbiFrame').addClass('slide-up', 200); $('.wblongbar').addClass('slide-uplongbar', 200); }});</script>",
```

As you can see, I use `.wblongbar`, which is contained in the 
`$( "body" ).append(json.csBlock[0].div);`

The script can't "find" the `.wblongbar div`

So, in what way do I append this script, without it **not** finding `.wblongbar`?
I've tried to change the order of the code but did nothing.

Comment: Remove all the spaces in script or any element you want to append.
Append all the data as a single string.

Comment: @AjayMakwana Alright, that works! Thank you very much... I've gotten the append code from some documentation and apparently it was coded wrong... Did not know this myself. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the spaces in script or any element you want to append. Append all the data as a single string.